# How to call a plugin function from front end form

Tags: plugins

I have a page template having a form which further have 3 input fields and and a submit button. I have a written a function in a plugin which inserts the retrieved values in database. I am trying to figure out what to write in action attribute of the form, so that when user clicks the submit button, the function gets executed?

Comment: Please file an [edit] and add all the relevant code and info that you have. Without code it is hard to help you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Output The Form

Can be done via [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

### What Should Be Set on Form Action

Leave it blank `<form action="">`. Make sure you avoid using reserved name as form field name like `name` or `p`. Otherwise your form submission will hit `404`.

### How Can We Validate or Process The Form?

Hook into `template_redirect`.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse149613_form_process' );

function wpse149613_form_process(){
    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) // assuming you're using POST and submit button name is 'submit'
        return;

    // Validate the form, verify nonce

    // process form

}
```

Hope it makes sense. This is how I usually handle form submission.

Comment: It has cleared lot of doubts. Will try to implement the same and mark this question closed once done. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's [another post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159548/custom-form-action-hook)! that can help you.

Basically you need to specify `admin_url( 'admin-post.php' )` as the action for the form and place a hidden input specifying a custom action.

Then you can register that action in your plugin so you can process the form information.

Example:

```
<form action="<?=admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ) ?>" method="POST">
    <!-- your inputs -->
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myplugin_mycustomaction"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Then in your PHP plugin can place the function that process that form this way

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_myplugin_mycustomaction',array( "class_that_owns_that_function", 'yourmethod' ) );

public function yourmethod()
{
    // Do what you want with $_POST variables
}
```

If the method is in the same class you can use $this instead of the name of owns the function.